# Copy excel row in different worksheet when cell dropdown "Yes" and when "No" removes the row if "Yes" was selected previously

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy excel row in different worksheet sheet 2 when cell dropdown "Yes" of Column F and when "No" removes the row if "Yes" was selected previously. I also wanted to check if duplicate exists in worksheet 2, then prompt user with "Yes", "No" button. If "Yes" then duplicate if "No" do nothing.

```
ColA:Customer Name  ColB:Customer Address   ColC:Customer City    ColD:Cust zip ColE:Tel     ColF:Yes/No
```

I have tried this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lastrow As Long
If UCase(Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Value) <> "YES" Then Exit Sub

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lastrow = Application.Max(4, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
          If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A1:A" & lastrow), _
        Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value) > 0 Then Exit Sub
        Response = MsgBox("Record already exists, add again?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + 256)
    If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    .Range("A" & lastrow).Resize(, 5).Value = _
        Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Resize(, 5).Value
End With
Response = MsgBox("Record added")
End Sub
```

Comment: `removes the row if "Yes" was selected previously` - 1) what row should be removed, in what sheet? 2) there should be some background for `"Yes" was selected previously` - doyou really need it? maybe you can change your requirements just as `when "No" removes the row` without `if "Yes" was selected previously`?

Comment: @simoco sorry didn't see your message.  1)Suppose in Sheet 1 for record on row 1, I had selected "Yes" in columnF. It copies the record in Sheet 2. Now for the same record in Sheet1 I select "No" in column F. The copied row gets removed from Sheet 2 2)Yes & No are two options, suppose i copy record by error by then wanted to undo the action. So that's why I wanted to do it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like this (code runs only if changed value in column `F`):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim Response
    Dim rng As Range, rngToDel As Range
    Dim fAddr As String

    If Intersect(Target, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        lastrow = Application.Max(4, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)

        If UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then

                Response = vbYes
                If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A1:A" & lastrow), _
                    Range("A" & Target.Row).Value) > 0 Then
                    Response = MsgBox("Record already exists, add again?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + 256)
                End If

                If Response = vbYes Then
                    .Range("A" & lastrow).Resize(, 5).Value = _
                        Range("A" & Target.Row).Resize(, 5).Value
                    MsgBox "Record added"
                End If

        ElseIf UCase(Target.Value) = "NO" Then
            With .Range("A4:A" & lastrow)
                Set rng = .Find(What:=Range("A" & Target.Row), _
                                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                    lookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                    MatchCase:=False)
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    fAddr = rng.Address
                    Do
                        If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                            Set rngToDel = rng.Resize(, 5)
                        Else
                            Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, rng.Resize(, 5))
                        End If
                        Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
                        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                    Loop While fAddr <> rng.Address
                End If

                If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                    rngToDel.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    MsgBox "Records from sheet2 removed"
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End With


ExitHere:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Resume ExitHere
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!! let me check :)

Comment: This is amazing!! I had a question. Right now the code fires when I re-click on the particular cell in column F. Is it possible to make the code fire on hitting Enter key or clicking off the next cell after data is entered in Column F

Comment: I think yes, it's possible, but code would be much harder (right now I don't see any simple solution for this). I would leave code as it is now:)